# How to handle domain model updates and immutability of stored events?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I understand that events in event sourcing should never be allowed to change. But what about the in-memory state? If the domain model needs to be updated in some way, shouldn't old event still be replayed to old models? I mean shouldn't it be possible to always replay events and get the *exact* same state as before or is it acceptable if this state evolves too as long as the stored events remains the same? Ideally I think I'd like to be able to get a state as it was with it's old models, rules and what not. But other than that I of course also want to replay old events into new models. What does the theory say about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Anticipate event structure changes

You should always try to reflect the fact that an event had a different structure in your event application mechanism (i.e. where you read events and apply them to the model). **After all, the earlier structure of an event was a valid structure at that time.**

This means that you need to be prepared for this situation. Design the event application mechanism flexible enough so that you can support this case.

#### Migrating stored events

Only **as a very last resort** should you migrate the stored events. If you do it, make sure you understand the consequences:

- Which other systems consumed the legacy events?
- Do we have a problem with them if we change a stored event?
- Does the migration work for our system (verify in a QA environment with a full data set)?